# "john --format=axcrypt" is not returning results

Tags: hash, password-cracking, brute-force, hashcat, john-the-ripper

I would like to open a mysterious old file that I found on my Hard Disk, the contents of which I do not know nor can I guess from its name (PB-mp4-rar.axx).

The file was password-protected with the program AxCrypt (as intuitable from the extension), whose installer I found on the same Hard Disk. The version is definitely <= 1.7.3180.0, let's say it's 1.x.

I assume the password is not something extremely hard so I would like to try opening it with JtR (or HashCat which I never used yet) using combinations of a wordlist I created and, in case of failure, trying brute force.
I found [this](https://github.com/openwall/john/blob/a63b64d2ab57606b4c6a8a005452c531c02fe8e6/run/axcrypt2john.py#L20) script and with the following command

```
sudo python3 axcrypt2john.py PB-mp4-rar.axx > PB.hash
```

I had the hash below written to a file (PB.hash).

```
PB-mp4-rar.axx:$axcrypt$*1*15000*d0747f65343a5d2325a8aba62b74e0fa*3be9c7eb033345078c8646b8657e2345de69cb2d3457e300
```

I launched

```
sudo john --format=AxCrypt --verbosity=5 PB.hash
```

and received this output

> initUnicode(UNICODE, UTF-8/ISO-8859-1)
> UTF-8 -> UTF-8 -> UTF-8
> Using default input encoding: UTF-8
> Loaded 1 password hash (AxCrypt [PBKDF2-SHA512/SHA1 AES 32/64])
> Cost 1 (iteration count) is 15000 for all loaded hashes
> Will run 2 OpenMP threads
> Loaded 9 hashes with 9 different salts to test db from test vectors
> Proceeding with single, rules:Single

but so far it hasn't yielded any results and I don't know if it ever will.

I tried to use HashCat too launching

```
hashcat -m 13200 -a 3 PB.hash
```

but returns

> Minimum password length supported by kernel: 0
> Maximum password length supported by kernel: 256
> Hashfile 'PB.hash' on line 1 (PB-mp4...8c8646b8657e2345de69cb2d3457e300): Signature unmatched
> No hashes loaded.

The `hashid` command returns

> Unknown hash

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: If `john --format=AxCrypt PB.hash` is running without error (you said "so far it hasn't yielded any results"?) ... then you're on the right track - you just have to try different attacks (wordlists, etc.)

Comment: I thought I had made a mistake because I found [this](https://github.com/openwall/john/issues/4292)

Comment: Indeed, if there is no built-in way to distinguish between 128 and 256, it might silently fail. This hashcat forum thread may be useful: https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-9450.html

Comment: Before using hashcat, did you format the hash the way it expects? https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes

Comment: I'm not sure about what format it expects so I have not manipulated the created file in any way. The string inside is the one posted above and I have given it as input to HashCat exactly as you see it