# John The Ripper succedeed in finding password without printing it

Tags: hash, password-cracking, brute-force, john-the-ripper

Some days ago I tried to found the password of a file encrypted with AxCrypt 1.x.
I tried John The Ripper and HashCat, but for unknown reason with the last one I failed, and I will open a new thread about this in the coming days.
Since I was not sure JtR could succeed, I made [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/266445/john-format-axcrypt-is-not-returning-results?noredirect=1#comment552168_266445) thread while the brute-force was running and a user in comments left me with a doubt: if there is no built-in way to distinguish between 128 and 256, it might silently fail.
So I made a try encrypting another file with AxCrypt 1.x using this password:

> abc123

I use [this](https://github.com/openwall/john/blob/a63b64d2ab57606b4c6a8a005452c531c02fe8e6/run/axcrypt2john.py#L20) to find the hash and I ran JtR. After some time it succeded, but it didn't print the password he found.
So I ran it again but the output says

> No password hashes left to crack

I made a [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UGof.jpg) of the terminal that explain better that me what happened.
I tried months previously to find the password of a .rar file with JtR and I succedeed after 90 seconds, but in that case the password was shown in the terminal.
I tried also [this](https://forum.axcrypt.net/axcrypt-brute-force/) following the guide with this regular expression

> [\w]?[\w]?[\w]?[\d]?[\d]?[\d]?

and after about a couple of hours it succeeded printing the right password.
At least now I know that finding the password is possible and that JtR can crack my other file with a lot more time without silently failing.

Anyone knows why and how to solve this funny and bizarre problem? I made some mistake that I cannot see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really funny or bizarre at all. John is doing [exactly what you're instructing](https://en.kali.tools/?p=1276#:%7E:text=Default%20level:%7E:text=or%20less%20verbose.-,Default%20level,-is%203.%20For)

The default verbosity level is 3, you're reducing that to 1 which means some (most) messages (including cracked passwords) will be suppressed. Verbosity >= 2 will print the cracked passwords.

As a sidenote, John typically stores cracked password/hash pairs in the potfile. If you have a file with a hash(es) that has already been cracked and just want to see what the corresponding password is, you can simply do `john --show <filename>` to get that information.

Comment: I made the screen with verbosity=1 but in the first thread I tried =5 and it was not printed. That's why I made the thread. However --show works, that's the important.